# Convert unicode chars to hex decimal value for use in operators

Tags: python, hex

Is there a way to convert Unicode chars? For example:

```
Uni = u'2f'
hexa = to_Hex(Uni)

print(hexa)
0x2f

Dec = int(hexa)
print(Dec)
47
```

I search everywhere, but could not find any answer.

Comment: Look at that https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
Uni = u'2f'

# convert to an integer
integer=int(Uni, base=16)

# convert to hex again (what for?)
hex_again=hex(integer)
```